# The discretization of a continuous markov chain, is still a markov chain?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, markov-process, binning

So I'm reading the [Guihenneuc-Jouyaux & Robert paper from 1998](https://www2.stat.duke.edu/%7Escs/Courses/Stat376/Papers/ConvergeDiagnostics/Discretize_CRobert_JASA98.pdf) about discretization of Markov Chains in which they claim that a naive discretization of a continuous Markov chain is not usually a Markov chain. I can't find a way to prove it, and i just need the proof that a naive discretization does not lead to a Markov chain. Does anyone know how to?

Comment: Could you please tell us what a "naive discretization" is so that we don't have to read the paper to understand your question?  BTW, "proof" is not relevant to your question: all you need is a single counterexample.  You might consider standard Brownian Motion, for instance, and let the measurable subset be $\mathcal A = (-\infty, \theta]$ for some fixed number $\theta,$ as given in the introduction to the paper.

Comment: For "naive discretization" i mean just split the chain in interval of times and use it as a DTMC without making any adjustment for it.

Comment: How do you "use" it, exactly?  By what mathematical process do you convert an entire interval of results into a single discrete value?

Comment: Well my idea was running a continuous process for a fixed amount of time, and take the exact value at the end of this fixed time. Once this is done that value will be the state of my discrete Markov chain but i fear this is not correct without any adjustment.

Comment: That would still be a Markov chain -- but it's not what the paper you reference is doing.

Comment: I know it's totally different, but then why would it still be a Markov Chain? That's my question

Comment: This is due to a basic logical fact that any proposition that is true of a set is true of a subset. Just look at the  independence criterion to be an MC: it's automatically satisfied, because independence of $X_t$ on all $X_s$ for $s\lt t$ *includes* independence of $X_i$ on all $X_j$ for $j\lt i$ where $i$ and $j$ are integral.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it's more clear now.